# PCIE GFX Card along with PCI GFX Card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, pci-express, pci

I have a complicated question with a restricted budget (Like 0$).

I have a PC with a GT220 graphics card which which has a limitation of being able to use only two of it's out of three. Now I need to use it's third output, either I need to find a custom firmware that allows 3 displays which I'm sure I'm not gonna find.

The other option is having another card for this purpose which is going to cost a lot, this card is still expensive here. So I find an old card which is a PCI card ATI Radeon 7000 32mb. I have inserted it into the PC and it is recognized by the OS as a display adapter, but doesn't give any display and gives the following error:

"The driver is trying to start the same as the driver for the posted display adapter."

So what should I do to get it working. The PCI card or the PCIE card to work as intended.

Regards

PS: I dont need high pixel count, I can lower it down to be able to use 3 Outputs, idc, just so you all know.

Comment: What OS? Modern copies of windows are happy with more than one driver. Older versions arn't. Its also worth checking if the old graphics card even has drivers.

Comment: Windows 10. It said Microsoft Basic Display Adapter. Usually this does gives the display on my PC when i dont have driver's installed. Could this be it?

Comment: Might be. Does the nvidia card have drivers installed? If you're running both off the 'basic' MS adaptor, that might explain it.

Comment: no. NVidia has its drivers and control panel.

Comment: "which has a limitation of being able to use only two of it's out of three." - This comment does not make sense.  Firmware can't change how hardware is designed.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: Just for the sake of the final answer, I removed the PCI Video card as it did not work in any way, even after installing video drivers for the card.